¿Cómo implemento un modelo de tensorflow lite en android?
tengo un problema. Estaba tratando de crear una aplicación de Android en Kotlin que fuera capaz de usar Mediapipe pose detector y un modelo de Tensorflow lite.
Para probar, he usado la aplicación que ya tienen de prueba los programadores de Mediapipe de Google en Git. Trate de implementarlo usando la opción que ofrece Android Estudio de crear una Interfaz (o una copia del modelo no se muy bien lo que es). Tras crearlo, copie y pegué el siguiente código en el MainActivity del programa.
val model = ClasificadorAndroid.newInstance(context)

// Creates inputs for reference.
val inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 24), DataType.FLOAT32)
inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer)

// Runs model inference and gets result.
val outputs = model.process(inputFeature0)
val outputFeature0 = outputs.outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer

// Releases model resources if no longer used.
model.close()

El nombre de ClasificatorAndroid me parece que se refiere a mi modelo Clasificador_Android.tflite. El principal problema que me surge es que ClasificadorAndroid no me lo reconoce. Llegados a este punto no se si tengo que seguir con esta ruta o si hay una opción más sencilla para resolver el problema.
En cuanto a donde tendría que estar el parámetro, yo creo que los parámetros deberían de estar la definición y cierre en el fichero CameraFragment.kt y la ejecución en PoseLandmarker.kt.
¿Alguna idea sobre como resolverlo?

Revisa que ninguna dependencía que tenga una clase que tal vez se use en ClasificadorAndroid, no marque error.

Lo primero que debes revisar es que el import de tu clase ClasificadorAndroid, debes asegurar que estás usando el paquete correcto.
Revisa que tienes lo siguiente:
import <package>.ClasificadorAndroid

Donde  es el paquete (estrucutra de directorios)  donde se encuentra la clase ClasificadorAndroid.
